# JAVA: Using methods from another class

Tags: java, oop, instantiation

I am a beginner programmer creating a battleship game for a JAVA course.  I've run into an issue where I cannot use methods that I have created in one class in the main class for the project.
BattleshipBard.java:

```
Public class BattleshipBoard {

   char[][] playerBoard = new char[10][10];
   char[][] opponentBoard = new char[10][10];

public void initBoard(char[][] board)
   {
      for(int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
      {
            for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
               board[x][i] = 'w';
            }
      }
   }

   public String toString(char[][] board)
   {
      String s  = "";
      for(int x = 1; x < 10; x++) {
         for(int i = 1; i <10; i++) {
            s += board[x][i];
            }
         s += "/n";
      }
   return s;
   }
}
```

Battleship.java:

```
public class Battleship 
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String win;
      BattleshipBoard[][] player = new BattleshipBoard[10][10];
      BattleshipBoard[][] opponent = new BattleshipBoard[10][10];

      initBoard(player[10][10]);
      win = toString(player[10][10]);
   }
}
```

I get this error when I try to run it.  I'm not sure why it is not finding the method in my BattleshipBoard.java file.

```
Battleship.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
      initBoard(player[10][10]);
      ^
  symbol:   method initBoard(BattleshipBoard)
  location: class Battleship
```

Thank you.

Comment: In the main method, create a BattleshipBoard object, assign it to a variable, and call methods off of it.

Comment: `BattleshipBoard battleshipBoard = new BattleshipBoard();` then `battleshipBoard.iniBoard(player)`. Also your player array should be an array of char, not BattleshipBoard.

Comment: Your code has a lot of issues, possibly too many to cover in a good single answer here and, as it stands, your question is rather broad. You may wish to take a look at the [official tutorial on Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html). It is well-written and will give you all of the tools you need to solve your issues here.

Comment: Are you aware that `BattleShipBoard` has two 10x10 chars arrays (that's 100 chars each for a total of 200) and that you are then making two 10x10 array of boards in your `BattleShip` main method? That's 200 boards with 200 chars for a grand total of 40,000 cells.

Answer (score 0):

```
BattleshipBoard bs = new BattleshipBoard();
```

the above creates an instance called bs
by the way i noticed Public when it should be lower case public

the next thing is, when you have instance bs instantiated call the method initBoard() such as bs.initBoard()

you are telling the instance to call the function into use, the function is initBoard (it is also called method, method/function meh! all the same)

also (new) is a keyword designed to allow the creation of a new instance BattleshipBoard() while you didn't explicitly create in the class BattleshipBoard() is automatically generated, it has the same name as the class but is in fact called a constructor method, constructor methods take on the name of the class but can include parameters such as

```
public BattleshipBoard(int width, int height){

}
```

finally, the person above me recommended making it static, static allows a method or field become globally available, this has its pluses and its negatives.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a class BattleshipBoard .. (internally this class holds the arrays for the boards).  However in your main code you are crating 10x10 BattlshipBoards (each of which holds a game state).

Recheck what your Class does.  Let BattleshipBoard hold the arrays and don't reference them outside of the class.  Provide methods in BattleshipBoard to initialize the game, to make opponents play, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`initBoard()` belongs to the `BattleshipBoard` class, you should be calling it from your objects instead like so:

```
player.initBoard();
opponent.initBoard();
```